# Is cherry-pick command generate the different hashcode of same commit?

Tags: git

I don't have good knowledge of cherry-pick. Just need to clear that a cherry-pick command generate the different hash code of same commit in different branch?
Actually I am cherry-picking the hash-code in different branch. And here I am noticing that it is generating different hash code of the existing commit. Is it the workflow of it or any issue is existin here?

Answer (score 7):

The commit hash is based not only on the content of the commit but also the time the commit was made. Since cherry-picking creates a new commit at the current time, it will generate a new hash code. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873169/is-sha-1-calculated-based-on-content) explains what goes into the hash.

In general you shouldn't really care about the hash, though.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for reminding me the fact regarding creating of hashcode.

Comment: And [in some ways] more importantly the id of the parent so even if you fix up the timestamps a cherry-picked commit will still have a different id.